# Capture "netsh dhcp server show scope"

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I need to capture the output from

```
netsh dhcp server show scope
```

which shows like:

```
==============================================================================
 Scope Address  - Subnet Mask    - State        - Scope Name          -  Comment
==============================================================================

 10.5.116.0     - 255.255.255.0  -Active        -LAN 1               -VLAN 1
 10.17.134.0    - 255.255.255.128-Active        -LAN 2               -VLAN 2
```

in powershell variables (if possible a array). So that I have line1 with Scope, Subnet, ... (e.g. $Line1['Scope'])

But I couldn´t get that managed. Could somebody help me to get a starting point here? Helpfull would be how I can capture a whole line.

Answer (score 1):

Server 2012 & Windows 8: DHCP Server Management module as described in [Powershell - DHCP Scopes in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177949/powershell-dhcp-scopes-in-powershell?rq=1)

Powershell V3 (possibly V2): Get the [Powershell Module for DHCP](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/05b1d766-25a6-45cd-a0f1-8741ff6c04ec) and use `Get-DHCPScope`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know netsh is the only way to manage DHCP using Powershell on servers except for W2K12 where [WMI DHCP Server Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh832732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exists.

By the way, you do not have to reinvent the wheel you will find a [PowerShell Module for DHCP](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/05b1d766-25a6-45cd-a0f1-8741ff6c04ec) which use netsh. I do not test it but it looks promizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Scope | export-csv C:\temp\dhcp.csv
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer for future readers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.